# htaccess script for clean url in existing site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to write a htaccess script to redirect requests to respective pages of my website. Below are few examples -

```
http://mysite.com/index.php to http://mysite.com/index
```

and

```
http://mysite.com/somefile.php?id=1&value=something to http://mysite.com/somefile/1/something
```

I can change existing links for redirection, plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&[a-z]+=(.*)$ $1/$2/$3 [R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for quickly answer can you write full .htaccess i am naive :(